# Puppet: disable echo of notify commands

Tags: puppet

I would like to print some messages and variable values while my configuration is applied.
I would also like to separate the output of different configuration blocks visually. so I use

```
notify {"\n\nINSTALL TOMCAT TO $target_folder":}
```

as described in puppet [tutorials](http://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/simple-debug-messages.html) and [documentation](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/2.6.8/type.html#notify).

Unfortunately the output does not really add readability to the whole log:

```
notice: 

INSTALL TOMCAT TO /opt/example/uiserver
notice: /Stage[main]//Node[dev-xyz.example.com]/Tomcat[uiserver_tomcat]/Notify[

INSTALL TOMCAT TO /opt/example/uiserver]

INSTALL TOMCAT TO /opt/example/uiserver'
```

Problem - instead of just printing the message, puppet also outputs an annoying echo `/message: defined 'message' as '`. Is there any way to eliminate it?

Using `withpath => false` did not help.

Puppet 2.7.17.

Answer (score 3):

Set --logdest to `syslog`.
It's `console` by default.

```
--logdest:
  Where to send messages. Choose between syslog, the console, and a log
  file. Defaults to sending messages to the console.
```

Comment: Where we have to add --logdest:syslog?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using the notice() function instead of the notify type as per http://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/simple-debug-messages.html

With the notice() function mesagee will be written to the puppetmaster's log instead of the client, but there won't be an echo line echo'd back.